# After a ClickOnce upgrade, how do I kill other (older) running instances of my app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mutex, clickonce

I want to ensure the following flow:

1. User is running the app
2. User runs ClickOnce launcher to get an update
3. After the update, the new version of the app runs **and the old version is killed**

**Can ClickOnce take care of this?**

**If not, can we handle this in our startup code?**
In our current startup code, we use a `Mutex` to prevent multiple instances of our app from running.  Currently, this logic says,
"If another instance is already running, kill myself."
We could change this logic to:
"If another instance is running and I am a newer version, kill the other instance; otherwise, kill myself."

*But how would we compare versions?* I could find the process and get its `FileVersion`, but that isn't the version I need. Is there a simple form of inter-process communication I could use to "ask" for the current version? If nothing else, I could write the running version to a file, but I was hoping to be more elegant than that.

Comment: Click once will replace the app, they should not be able to run a previous version. Is that what you are experiencing?

Comment: @crowcoder, Yes, if the previous version is still running during upgrade, it is not stopped and the upgrade proceeds and launches a new instance.